# Вывести функцию в переменную

Tags: php, переменные, функции

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь в функции есть "echo". Как сделать, чтобы всё это передавалось в одну переменную?

Как пагинацию передать в переменную, а не выводить?

```
function pagination($all, $lim, $prev, $curr_link, $curr_css, $link) {
        echo '<div class="pagination">';
        $first = $curr_link - $prev;
        if ($first < 1) $first = 1;
        $last = $curr_link + $prev;
        if ($last > ceil($all / $lim)) $last = ceil($all / $lim);
        $y = 1;
        if ($first > 1) echo '<a href="'.$link.
        '?page='.$y.
        '"><span>1</span></a>|';
        $y = $first - 1;
        if ($first > 2) {
            echo '<a href="'.$link.
            '?page='.$y.
            '"><span>...</span></a>|';
        } else {
            for ($i = 2; $i < $first; $i++) {
                if ($i == $first) {
                    echo '<a href="'.$link.
                    '?page='.$y.
                    '"><span>'.$i.
                    '</span></a>';
                } else {
                    echo '<a href="'.$link.
                    '?page='.$y.
                    '"><span>'.$i.
                    '</span></a>|';
                }
            }
        }

        for ($i = $first; $i < $last + 1; $i++) {
            if ($i == $curr_link) {
                if ($i == $last) { ?>
                    < span class = "<?php echo $curr_css; ?>" > < span > <? echo $i ?> < /span></span >
                        <? php
                } else { ?>
                    < span class = "<?php echo $curr_css; ?>" > < span > <? echo $i ?> < /span></span > <? php echo '|'; ?>
                    <? php
                }
            } else {
                $alink = "<a href=\"".$link.
                "?page=".$i;
                if ($i == $last) {
                    $alink. = "\"><span>".$i.
                    "</span></a>";
                } else {
                    $alink. = "\"><span>".$i.
                    "</span></a>|";
                }
                echo $alink;
            }
        }

        $y = $last + 1;
        if ($last < ceil($all / $lim) and ceil($all / $lim) - $last > 2) echo '|<a href="'.$link.
        '?page='.$y.
        '"><span>...</span></a>|';
        $e = ceil($all / $lim);
        if ($last < ceil($all / $lim))
            echo '<a href="'.$link.
        '?page='.$e.
        '"><span>'.$e.
        '</span></a>';
        echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Ну так и накапливайте строки в переменной вместо их вывода. А ещё лучше - не заниматься подобным... э... нескажучем. А использовать [правильные листалки страниц][1].


  [1]: http://karaboz.ru/?p=12

Comment: дак изменил echo на $page2= просто выводиться пустота.

Comment: дак изменил echo на $page2= просто выводиться пустота.
    
    как то так... 
    $page2.=

Comment: @bajex, а вернуть эту переменную из функции?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая штука как [буферизация вывода](https://php.net/manual/ru/book.outcontrol.php)

```
ob_start();
// тут ваш код
$buffer = ob_get_content();
ob_end_clean();
```

Переменная buffer будет содержать все, что было выведено между этими двумя строками, реального вывода не произойдет

Comment: Вообщем убрал элементы функции и поместил все в переменную.

Comment: вместо
`$buffer = ob_get_content();
ob_end_clean();`
можно юзать `$buffer = ob_get_clean();`